# Supervised classifier for nested interval data and ordinal classes

Tags: classification, supervised-learning, gaussian-mixture-distribution, finite-mixture-model, constraint

I'm having trouble formalizing the following classification problem:

- Let $x_i$ denote univariate (scalar), continuous, real data points
- Let $y_i \in \mathbb{N}$ be their corresponding labels
- Classes are ordinal in the sense that $y_i = 0$ corresponds to a regular/normal condition, while $y_i > 0$ correspond to increasing levels of "irregularity" or "abnormality".
- The regular class $x_i | y_i = 0$ can be assumed to follow a unimodal
  distribution. There is a consistency constraint whereby we expect training data classified as irregular to have unimodal
  or bimodal distributions, with modes increasingly farther away from the mean of the regular class.
- If there is a contradiction in the training data, we may deal with it in a number of ways, including: ignoring both contradicting classes/modes; ignoring the one with the smaller sample size, higher variance, or farther away the mean of the regular class;
- The best possible training data will therefore have all $y_i > 0$ follow bimodal distributions, the modes being properly nested inside each other with the innermost pair of modes containing the mean/mode of the distribution of the regular class.
- Not all classes may have representatives in the training data, but it is required to predict/interpolate class membership based on the data for some pre-determined upper limit of classes $y_i <= k$. For example, when only "normal" samples $y_i = 0$ are given, it is desirable to classify samples say, more than 2 SDs away from the mean as class $y = 1$ and samples more than 3 SDs away as $y = 2$ given $k = 2$. Similarly, given only samples for classes $y = 1$ or $y = 2$, it will be necessary to estimate the range of regular/"normal" samples.

Is there a model that would do at least part of what I want? Perhaps a modification of a mixture model that is modified so that it's 1. supervised, 2. includes the consistency constraints.

If that helps, you may assume normals or mixtures of normals; I may try to stick a power transform into the model later.